# Is it possible to set up an SSD Cache on a macbook pro?

Tags: ssd, macbook, cache

I have a mid 2010 MBP. I would like to upgrade the HDD so that I get more space, and this isn't a problem. I'd also like to replace the optical drive with an SSD and then configure that as the cache for the HDD. I've done lots of searching, but still no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The better answer for what you are doing is a Momentus XT HD.  I have a 750 GB HD that has an (8 or 16) GB SSD built in I forget which.  Point is, it's faster than a 7200 RPM HD by itself, and you get to keep your optical drive.

Comment: +1. Not to knock your answer, but these drives do have a firmware issue that occasionally (i.e. not all drives) will have a 1-second delay before reading from it. Something to keep in mind (I have one and replaced it with full SSD for this reason).